# Expanding width of Combobox

Tags: python, pyqt5, qcombobox

I have a Qcombobox, which I want to set a specific width, which is not depending on item width. I have looked around and find some tips and hints only for C++. I do not have any knowledge on that language!!

What I get by first run:

[image]

What I want to get by first run:

[image]

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())
        combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(combo)
        combo.addItems(["item1", "item2", "item3"])
        combo.activated[str].connect(self.onActivatedText)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def onActivatedText(self, text):
        print(text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

An ugly solution is:

```
        combo.addItems(["item1     ", "item2     ", "item3     "])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> minimumContentsLength : int
>
> This property holds the minimum number of characters that should fit into the combobox.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())
        
        combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        
        self.layout().addWidget(combo)
        combo.addItems(["item1", "item2", "item3"])
        combo.activated[str].connect(self.onActivatedText)
        
        combo.setMinimumContentsLength(30)                 # +++

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def onActivatedText(self, text):
        print(text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You must set a minimum width appropriate to the QComboBox:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())
        combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.layout().addWidget(combo)
        combo.addItems(["item1", "item2", "item3"])
        combo.setMinimumWidth(100)
        combo.activated[str].connect(self.onActivatedText)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def onActivatedText(self, text):
        print(text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]